# Local Notification custom sound NOT playing after OS8.3

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

As soon as Apple updated their OS to 8.3 my local custom sounds weren't playing.

I've done everything right, because it worked <=8.2, so code shouldn't be an issue, but just in case this is how i've created my notifications:

**FYI they are 30 sec or less**

First I converted them to caf format using [Apples supplied code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW6)

Then I added it to my project. I have verified it's in my resource bundle. I have also verified they are assigned to the target.

It's still not playing, but did in all previous OS versions.

Here is my schedule method:

```
- (void) scheduleLocalNotification {
NSString *localNotificationSound;
localNotificationSound = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Clock" ofType:@".caf"];

UILocalNotification *timerDoneNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
timerDoneNotification.soundName = localNotificationSound;
timerDoneNotification.alertBody = @"Time Up!";
timerDoneNotification.alertAction = @"Reset";
timerDoneNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:secondsLeft];
timerDoneNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:timerDoneNotification];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't read the part about how it has to be a non localized resource:

> You can package the audio data in an aiff, wav, or caf file. Then, in Xcode, add the sound file to your project as a nonlocalized resource of the app bundle.

So all I did was wrap the file name in `stringWithFormat` and it started working post v8.3

```
timerDoneNotification.soundName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", localNotificationSound];
```